# Executing custom code inside raised exception

Tags: python

I've got several methods which can raise my custom exception. After the exception has been raised, I need to handle it, let's say log message to console and save it into database.

I was thinking about a crazy workaround described in post title - I could move that custom code with logging and DB-saving into `__init__` method of my custom exception, so everytime the exception is raised, I would just silence it, since all needed stuff would be done on exception initialization.

I'm aware of that the exception `__init__` itself can raise another exception, but that can be handled too :)

Did anyone tried that?

And why is it crazy idea? :)

-

## edit:

I know it's kinda crazy, I'm just curious of your opinion. I will try to enclose what I want to achieve:

I'm working with remote data and when communicating to other servers through network, some problems could appear, every one at some other place:
1. network error - on creating connection.
2. HTTP errors (404, 500, etc.) - after connection;
3. remote server can return some other errors too

Since these problems occur in several different places, I created my custom exception:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass
```

and raise it everywhere, when I can catch them, for example:

```
try:
    conn.open(url)
except HTTPException as e:
    raise CustomException('http')
```

That's just a pseudo-example.

This CustomException is catched somewher higher and in almost every place I handle this the same way, i.e.:

```
try:
     place.populate()
except CustomException as e:
     handle_exception(e)
     return False
```

And `handle_exception` saves info about problem to database, does other things also like saving `place`'s object status and acccess date, but always updates the same things.

So I was just wondering if putting that `handle_exception` code inside `__init__` would be really crazy idea, since it is done everytime the exception is raised.

Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: Do you have an example. You lost me...

Comment: You can do logging and DB-saving inside __init__ of custom exception. But I don't think that is the way we should do it. Normally writing like this in a big project will make code unreadable for yourself and others who will work.

Comment: Why would you want to package exception handling into the exception object? If you want to trigger some logging, just trigger some logging without an exception. Exceptions should be used for "exceptional" circumstances. If you're not treating it as an exception, there's no reason for it to *be* an exception.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I updated my example above

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're suggesting two separate things. Firstly, there's the idea of having some custom code within an exception, which is far from crazy and is quite doable.

Example:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, Errors):
        # do stuff here
```

However, you alluded to automatically catching the exception every time it's raised. The reason that isn't done is pretty simple, if it's not an error then don't make it an exception. I have trouble imagining that there would be any reason to make a class an exception if you don't plan on actually doing anything with it at any point.

Personally if you want substantial logic on raising an exception (a little hard to comment on this without knowing your particular goal) I would suggest putting a logger in the `__init__` method and then put your logic directly in a `try/except` which is afterall, exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do something like this, which as others have said is a questionable goal, I'd suggest routing the messages through a [`logging.Logger`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects) in your exception's `__init__`, then attaching [`logging.Handler`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects) for logging to the DB, printing to the console, or what ever you want.  Then users of your libraries can control (and extend) the system in a much easier, more standardized way.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, but I'm doing others things there too, like updating object status, etc.